# The output buffer of sample and hold

Tags: amplifier, buffer, sample-and-hold

I saw some sample and hold circuits from the Internet,and i find there will be a buffer in the output,so i want to ask what does that buffer do for the sample and hold,can i use two stage amplifier as that buffer?

[image]

The two stage amp schematic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly the output buffer presents a really high impedance to the storage capacitor so it does not discharge significantly into the next stage.

Comment: Then why don't we just add a high resistance instead of the output buffer?

Comment: @ShineSun if you just added a high resistance it would act as a voltage divider with the input impedance of whatever comes next and you would have a different voltage at the input.

Comment: Thankyou!@Trevor

Comment: Do you think can the two-stage amp act as a output buffer?

Comment: @ShineSun "two stage amp" is meaningless without a drawing or schematic. It could mean a zillion things.

Comment: sorry for that @Trevor,the schematic of  two stage amp is as below

Comment: @ShineSun that looks like a simple op-amp, so yes. Though why you would not use a commercial op-amp IC I have no idea.

Comment: Because i have a two-stage amp schematic,though it is strage now.Do you have the commercial op-amp schematic?